# Structure alignment in C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I am working with SQL VDI and attempting to pass a structure from C# to C++ via a COM interface.  The structure is defined in the C++ header as:

```
#pragma pack(8)
struct VDConfig
    {
    unsigned long deviceCount;
    unsigned long features;
    unsigned long prefixZoneSize;
    unsigned long alignment;
    unsigned long softFileMarkBlockSize;
    unsigned long EOMWarningSize;
    unsigned long serverTimeOut;
    unsigned long blockSize;
    unsigned long maxIODepth;
    unsigned long maxTransferSize;
    unsigned long bufferAreaSize;
    } ;
```

To emulate this, I have defined the structure in C# as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct VDConfig 
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint deviceCount;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public uint features;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public uint prefixZoneSize;
    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public uint alignment;
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public uint softFileMarkBlockSize;
    [FieldOffset(20)]
    public uint EOMWarningSize;
    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public uint serverTimeout;
    [FieldOffset(28)]
    public uint blockSize;
    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public uint maxIODepth;
    [FieldOffset(36)]
    public uint maxTransferSize;
    [FieldOffset(40)]
    public uint bufferAreaSize;
}
```

I have also tried to define the structure as LayoutKind.Sequential and tried it with Pack=8.  However I define the structure, when I attempt to pass it to the function, it fails and I receive the error "Alignment must be 2**n and <= system allocation granularity."  I've tried defining the function that accepts the structure as:

```
int CreateEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string instanceName,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string name,
            IntPtr config);
```

and

```
int CreateEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string instanceName,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string name,
            ref VDConfig config);
```

I get the same result with either definition.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit:
In looking a little closer, I'm also getting the error "Device count must be in [1..64]."  I'm setting the device count to 1 and in concert with the error above, it almost looks like the function isn't getting my structure at all.  Don't know if this helps or not, but maybe it'll spark something for someone.

Per request, here are the interface structures.  In C++:

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("d0e6eb07-7a62-11d2-8573-00c04fc21759")
IClientVirtualDeviceSet2 : public IClientVirtualDeviceSet
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateEx( 
        /* [in] */ LPCWSTR lpInstanceName,
        /* [in] */ LPCWSTR lpName,
        /* [in] */ struct VDConfig *pCfg) = 0;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OpenInSecondaryEx( 
        /* [in] */ LPCWSTR lpInstanceName,
        /* [in] */ LPCWSTR lpSetName) = 0;

};
```

And my C# version:

```
[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("d0e6eb07-7a62-11d2-8573-00c04fc21759")]
public interface IClientVirtualDeviceSet2
{
    void CreateEx([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string instanceName,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string name,
        [In]ref VDConfig config);

    void OpenInSecondaryEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string instanceName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lpSetName);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried sequential with pack(8) together without FieldOffset?

Comment: Yes.  I get the same result with that.

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem.  It just doesn't like the value you specified for the VDConfig.alignment member.  You ought to follow its advice and use a value that is a power of 2 and <= 65536.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference.  Tried it with alignment=2 and alignment=8 and still get the same error.

Comment: Also, oddly enough, in the C++ example, alignment is set to 0.

Comment: Should you add COM DLL directly to your project?

Comment: I'd like to if I could.  The dll that contains the COM classes is sqlvdi.dll, but when I attempt to add it to the project or view it in OleView, it acts like it isn't a COM dll.

Comment: So I guess you are doing something like in this tutorial? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx . Maybe showing the interface mapping will help. I suspect the interface mapping part.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  I've added the interfaces into the queston.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who comes across this, this is the answer:

As you can see in `vdi.h`, `IClientVirtualDeviceSet2` "inherits" from `IClientVirtualDeviceSet`.  As far as COM is concerned, there is no such thing as interface inheritance.

Therefore, when calling `CreateEx` on `IClientVirtualDeviceSet2`, you're actually calling `Create` on `IClientVirtualDeviceSet` (because `Create` is the first method in the `vtable` of that combined `IClientVirtualDeviceSet` + `IClientVirtualDeviceSet2`).  That's why you end up getting invalid parameters.

The fix for this is to create a single interface (`IClientVirtualDeviceSet2`) with *all* the methods, `IClientVirtualDeviceSet` first, then the two `IClientVirtualDeviceSet2` methods (obviously in order).  This ensures when `CreateEx()` is called, it uses the correct `DispId`.

I'm sure you could probably use inheritance and set the DispIdAttribute accordingly:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dispidattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

but there is probably little point.

Comment: I needed this answer so much, I was getting so frustrated. Turns out, you _cannot_ use inheritance and `DispId` for sqlvdi because the C++ interface does not support `IDispatch`, which is presumably also why you can't generate an interop assembly from the dll.